# wrap ul list with background check marks around image

Tags: html, css

How do I wrap a ul list around an image when I'm using an check mark image for the list?  I know there is the list-style-image property but I've read there are cross browser issues with it.

The html was created with a WYSIWYG editor so I'd prefer to fix this in css.

Here is my html/css:



    test

```
<style>
    ul.list-tick li {
        background-image: url("http://www.psc-cfp.gc.ca/ppc-cpp/images/small-check-mark.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        list-style: none outside none;
        padding: 0 0 7px 23px !important;
    }

</style>
```

```
<p><img style="margin: 0px 10px 10px; float: left;" alt="a"
        src="http://www.car-myspace-layouts.com/backgrounds/lamborghini/Lambo_gallardo_153_1024x768.jpg" width="97" height="125" /></p>
<p>

<ul class="list-tick">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</li>
    <li>consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
    <li>Duis risus magna, vehicula quis faucibus eget, dictum id eros. </li>
    <li>Fusce sed quam a mi accumsan lacinia posuere quis quam.</li>
    <li>Phasellus vel justo urna. Nulla scelerisque posuere nisi, sit amet feugiat est egestas sed.</li>
    <li>Cras id lectus sed sem bibendum luctus sed eu justo.</li>
    <li>Ut vel magna mauris, et hendrerit lectus. Praesent non nulla orci. Sed eget diam et risus pulvinar dapibus porta ac nisi. </li>
    <li>Aliquam blandit orci a mi volutpat sagittis. Donec lorem ligula, rutrum a scelerisque quis, sollicitudin ut lorem. </li>
    <li>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that code should work, can you show a link to the site so we can see the error or show us a jsfiddle?  The only thing that I can think of why that wouldn't work is a conflict on the list-tick class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think I've come up with a solution that works. The only modification I made to your HTML was to add a `<span>` tag inside of every `<li>` element.

See it live: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/7C6rg/

```
p { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 23px 0 0; }
ul.list-tick { 
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 23px; }
ul.list-tick li span {
    background: url("http://www.psc-cfp.gc.ca/ppc-cpp/images/small-check-mark.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 7px 23px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -23px; }
```

HTML:

```
<p><img alt="a"
src="http://www.car-myspace-layouts.com/backgrounds/lamborghini/Lambo_gallardo_153_1024x768.jpg" width="97" height="125" /></p>
<ul class="list-tick">
    <li><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span></li>
    <li><span>consectetur adipiscing elit</span></li>
    <li><span>Duis risus magna, vehicula quis faucibus eget, dictum id eros.</span></li>
    <li><span>Fusce sed quam a mi accumsan lacinia posuere quis quam.</span></li>
    <li><span>Phasellus vel justo urna. Nulla scelerisque posuere nisi, sit amet feugiat est egestas sed.</span></li>
    <li><span>Cras id lectus sed sem bibendum luctus sed eu justo.</span></li>
    <li><span>Ut vel magna mauris, et hendrerit lectus. Praesent non nulla orci. Sed eget diam et risus pulvinar dapibus porta ac nisi.</span></li>
    <li><span>Aliquam blandit orci a mi volutpat sagittis. Donec lorem ligula, rutrum a scelerisque quis, sollicitudin ut lorem.</span></li>
    <li><span>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Clever solution. I wish I had thought of that!

Comment: Thanks, but I think your solution is probably more scalable/reusable than mine. Cleverness only goes so far ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a background image for the icon. The block level elements still exist behind the image, padding has just been added to keep them from overlapping the float. You can see that in this example I made. Note the blue and red borders. These correspond to a `p` and your `ul`

http://jsfiddle.net/QdDpk/1/

I don't think you can get your background images to dynamically place. I would just use images for the bullets. I've never heard that these are UNreliable, but if you have source for this share it.

Comment: Looks like [this link](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical05.htm) might have what you're looking for.

Comment: The only thing not supported according to Wex's link are very old browsers like IE6, Safari 1.0, and Opera 6. I think you can safely use images for bullets these days. Thanks for the link @Wex